# Error al instalar proyecto React (Could not resolve dependency: peer react@"^17.0.2" from @mui/icons-material@5.2.0)

Tags: reactjs, npm, docker

tengo un aplicación dockerizada de React. Y al hacer docker-compose build se ejecuta npm install.
El proyecto estaba funcionando bien, ¿por qué se producen estos errores, se actualizan las dependencias de las imágenes que docker descarga de la nube?

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @mui/icons-material@5.2.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.6.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     @emotion/react@"^11.6.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.6.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!       @emotion/styled@"^11.6.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       5 more (@mui/system, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/material, ...)
npm ERR!     5 more (@mui/system, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/material, ...)
npm ERR!   13 more (@emotion/styled, @fortawesome/react-fontawesome, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.2" from @mui/icons-material@5.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!   @mui/icons-material@"^5.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.2" from @mui/icons-material@5.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!     @mui/icons-material@"^5.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /root/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-04-04T12_38_43_143Z-debug-0.log

Update de la pregunta: Aquí se puede ver el package.json que estoy utilizando.

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^2.11.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.6.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.0",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.0",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.0.1",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^2.1.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.7.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.6",
    "jspdf": "^2.3.0",
    "match-sorter": "^6.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
    "yup": "^0.32.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el contenido de tu `package.json`?